# Word for how much of a professional?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a word which refers to how much of a professional someone is in a particular domain or endeavor.

For example, let's assume we're talking about playing the piano. The question might be

> What is your ____ in playing the piano?

Possible answers may be:

> I am a sporadic pianist.
>
> I am a hobbyist.
>
> I am a career pianist.

**Expertise** and **proficiency** (and [synonyms](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/expertise)) are not quite right. It's possible that someone who plays the piano infrequently and only as a hobby plays quite expertly. Someone can play the piano professionally but with limited proficiency.

I am open to different parts of speech. A neutral connotation seems preferable. If no suitable word exists, a term or phrase would be acceptable. I am considering "vocation(al) level".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After reading your comment, I am now aware that you are asking about a person's level of [dedication](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dedication).

You could ask,

> What is your level of dedication to playing the piano?

It would be more natural to ask,

> How dedicated are you to playing the piano?

The most natural way of asking would be the simplest,

> How often/frequently do you play the piano?

I'm not sure *ability* is what you're looking for, as suggested by Edwin Ashworth. As you said,

> It's possible that someone who plays the piano infrequently and only as a hobby plays quite expertly.

Hope this helps!